# A smart way to export c++ polymorphic functions with boost.python

Tags: c++, python, templates, boost, polymorphism

I have a highly polymorphic c++ function that can be called with nearly 20 diferent types.

In order to expose it to python I'm doing something like this:

```
#include originalFunctionNamespace.hpp

template<class T>
    T foo(T x)
    {
        return orignalFunctionNamespace::foo(x);
    }
```

but then to call them from python I have to specialize the functions with each type they support:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module_foo)
{
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type1>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type2>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type3>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type4>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type5>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type6>);
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::type7>);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def("foo", foo<orignalFunctionNamespace::typeN>);
}
```

This works, but I can't stop thinking that there must be a smarter way to do it. Since I have to do it for many many functions, things are getting big and super repetitive.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be polymorphism, just function overloading.

Comment: Not really a better way but you could try to use the preprocessor to shorten each line and "using namespace originalFunctionNamespace;" to shorten them further. That deos not solve the repetition but at least saves you a lot of text.

Comment: @interjay the function can receive many types as input and will output many different types accordingly. "A function that can evaluate to or be applied to values of different types is known as a polymorphic function." right?

Comment: @Nobody: wouldn't "using namespace originalFunctionNamespace;" prevent me from using the same names for the functions in python? I know what you mean anyway, tnx :)

Comment: @quiuquio: I wouldn't call this polymorphism because the actual function that is called is determined at compile-time rather than dynamically. Plus, in the context of C++ the term polymorphism refers to objects with virtual functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a possible use for typelist magic, to me.

If you're using (or can use) the new C++0x standard, you can write something like this:

```
template <typename ArgType>
void def_foo_overloads()
{
    def("foo", foo<ArgType>);
    // last type in list
}
template <typename ArgType, typename... MoreArgTypes>
void def_foo_overloads()
{
    def("foo", foo<ArgType>);
    def_foo_overloads(MoreArgTypes...);
}

// use it like:
def_foo_overloads<orignalFunctionNamespace::type1,
                  orignalFunctionNamespace::type2,
                  ...
                  orignalFunctionNamespace::typeN> ();
```

If you don't have access to the new standard, you can do the equivalent thing using the old recursive typelists.

Comment: or: `template<typename... Types> void def_overloads() { std::initializer_list<int> { (def("foo", foo<Types>), void(), 0)... }; }`

Comment: It's not specific to `std::initializer_list<T>` either. Every construction that uses the new list initialization syntax guarantees the order of evaluation of its parameters, even when it's equivalent to e.g. a constructor call (where the only guarantee is the sequence point before entering the body of the constructor, as usual). So e.g. `std::pair<int, int>(++i, ++i)` is bad whereas `std::pair<int, int> { ++i, ++i }` is fine. `std::initializer` is used here because it can accept an arbitrary number of arguments. I personally use an empty type with a variadic constructor.

Comment: @Useless: sorry but.. isn't it the same thing? From "//use is like:" I understand that I would have to write every function specialization the same way I was doing before, and I would have to create a def_XXX_overloads() for every function. This said, typelists may carry the key for my question. Thank you!

Comment: The point of this approach is that you can write a single `def_overloads` function template, and pass it a list of all the valid argument types.  You don't write anything extra per overload except list the argument type.  Now, if you have more than one function overload set to handle (say you have a group of similar functions called `bar` taking different argument types as well), you may need something a bit trickier to parameterize `def_overloads` by the overloaded function name.  Is that what you meant?